# Javascript filter based on id

Tags: javascript

I have three kind of entities in my er diagram.
**Province**, **District** and **City**.

Relationship is **City** belongs to **District** and **District** belongs to the **Province**.

this is my database table
region.

```
id | region_name      | region_parent_id
1  | Western province | null 
2  | Colombo          | 1
3  | Gampaha          | 1
4  | Kaluthara        | 1
5  | Nugegoda         | 2
6  | Maharagama       | 2
7  | Central province | null
8  | Kandy            | 7
9  | Mathale          | 7
10 | theldeniya       | 8
11 | penideniya       | 8
```

If I derive the relationships I would be like this,

**Western province**

Colombo

```
  Nugegoda
  Maharagama
```

Gampaha

Kaluthara

**Central province**

Kandy

```
Theldeniya
Penideniya
```

Mathale

I get this data as an array of objects like this,

```js
const regions = [
{id:1,region_name:"Western province",region_parent_id:null},
{id:2,region_name:"Colombo",region_parent_id:1},
{id:3,region_name:"Gampaha",region_parent_id:1},
{id:4,region_name:"Kaluthara",region_parent_id:1},
{id:5,region_name:"Nugegoda",region_parent_id:2},
{id:6,region_name:"Maharagama",region_parent_id:2},
{id:7,region_name:"Central province",region_parent_id:null},
{id:8,region_name:"Kandy",region_parent_id:7},
{id:9,region_name:"Mathale",region_parent_id:7},
{id:10,region_name:"theldeniya",region_parent_id:8},
{id:11,region_name:"penideniya",region_parent_id:8}

]

console.log(regions.filter(e=> !e.region_parent_id ))
```

I could easily get the provinces like this.

```
console.log(regions.filter(e=> !e.region_parent_id ))
```

But how could I get districts list and the cities list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```js
var parId = prompt("Enter region parent id : " ) ;

const regions = [
  {id:1,region_name:"Western province",region_parent_id:null},
  {id:2,region_name:"Colombo",region_parent_id:1},
  {id:3,region_name:"Gampaha",region_parent_id:1},
  {id:4,region_name:"Kaluthara",region_parent_id:1},
  {id:5,region_name:"Nugegoda",region_parent_id:2},
  {id:6,region_name:"Maharagama",region_parent_id:2},
  {id:7,region_name:"Central province",region_parent_id:null},
  {id:8,region_name:"Kandy",region_parent_id:7},
  {id:9,region_name:"Mathale",region_parent_id:7},
  {id:10,region_name:"theldeniya",region_parent_id:8},
  {id:11,region_name:"penideniya",region_parent_id:8}
]

function belong(dis) {
  var getProvince = regions.find( e => e.id === dis ) ;
  if ( getProvince ) {
    console.log("==========" + getProvince.region_name + "==========" ) ;
    regions.map( c => {if (c.region_parent_id === dis ) console.log(c.region_name + " " + c.id +" Parent:(" + c.region_parent_id +")") } )
  }
}

belong( parseInt(parId) );
```

Comment: This works! =) and how could I get the cities which are belongs to a city. If I pass district id 2 how do I get the cities belongs to that district?

Comment: @Ehsan, it seems like not that tough question, you should learn how to solve problem instead of ask for code. I think you can use Map data structure solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter in below way you will get your desired result.

```js
const regions = [
  {id:1,region_name:"Western province",region_parent_id:null},
  {id:2,region_name:"Colombo",region_parent_id:1},
  {id:3,region_name:"Gampaha",region_parent_id:1},
  {id:4,region_name:"Kaluthara",region_parent_id:1},
  {id:5,region_name:"Nugegoda",region_parent_id:2},
  {id:6,region_name:"Maharagama",region_parent_id:2},
  {id:7,region_name:"Central province",region_parent_id:null},
  {id:8,region_name:"Kandy",region_parent_id:7},
  {id:9,region_name:"Mathale",region_parent_id:7},
  {id:10,region_name:"theldeniya",region_parent_id:8},
  {id:11,region_name:"penideniya",region_parent_id:8}
];

var province = regions.filter(e => !e.region_parent_id);

province.forEach(p => { 
  p.district = regions.filter(e => e.region_parent_id == p.id); 
  // Uncomment following snippet if you want to have cities list inside district object also.
  //p.district.forEach(d => { 
  //  d.city = regions.filter(e => e.region_parent_id == d.id);
  //});
  
  var districtIds = p.district.map(d => d.id);
  p.city = regions.filter(e => districtIds.includes(e.region_parent_id));
});

console.log(province);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const regions = [
  { id: 1, region_name: "Western province", region_parent_id: null },
  { id: 2, region_name: "Colombo", region_parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 3, region_name: "Gampaha", region_parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 4, region_name: "Kaluthara", region_parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 5, region_name: "Nugegoda", region_parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 6, region_name: "Maharagama", region_parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 7, region_name: "Central province", region_parent_id: null },
  { id: 8, region_name: "Kandy", region_parent_id: 7 },
  { id: 9, region_name: "Mathale", region_parent_id: 7 },
  { id: 10, region_name: "theldeniya", region_parent_id: 8 },
  { id: 11, region_name: "penideniya", region_parent_id: 8 }
];

const provinces = regions.filter(region => !region.region_parent_id);
for (let i = 0; i < provinces.length; i++) {
  const currentProvince = provinces[i];
  // get districts for this now
  currentProvince.districts = regions.filter(region => region.region_parent_id === currentProvince.id);
  for (let j = 0; j < provinces[i].districts.length; j++) {
    const currentDistrict = provinces[i].districts[j];
    // get cities for the district
    currentDistrict.cities = regions.filter(region => region.region_parent_id === currentDistrict.id);
  }
}

console.log(provinces)
```